# Why are presta valves better than schrader valves

Tags: valves

I have a couple of bikes and tire sizes.  Some have presta valves some have schrader valves.  I find the the tires that have presta valves hard to pump and that they seem to lose air way more often.  Why do newer bikes and most high end bikes use presta valves?  Other than being "newer" and I guess more "high end" what is the advantage?  I can understand for road bikes.  However, the bikes I ride most are gravel and commuter bikes with 700x35c to 700x40c tires.  Does it make sense for me to just switch to schrader valves?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/80748/considering-modern-bicycle-trends-2021-why-are-presta-valves-still-the-domina

Comment: Yes! And I totally agree!!! I am somewhat of a newbie and already I see the gimmickery in just pushing presta. In some cases like mine, I feel Schrader makes way more sense. Weight is not much of an issue, I have somewhat wide rims, I find it easier to use the hand pumps with Schrader, etc... But on a road bike with thin tires where speed and performance matter then yes to presta.

Comment: You can't really "switch" to Schrader valves: they require a larger hole in the rim. Drilling the rim impacts its structural integrity (in which extend, I don't know), and certainly voids the warranty.

Comment: Makes sense.  I did notice though on my rim that the presta valve is wider than the opening and the little lockring like thing on it covers the gap.  So I'm thinking that maybe I can still fit a shcrader valve in it.  If not then ya I'm stuck with the presta.

Comment: This question is wrongly asked and I suggest to close it as at least opinion based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are both Schrader and Presta valves still used on tubes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8157/why-are-both-schrader-and-presta-valves-still-used-on-tubes)

Answer (score -2):

The easy way to fill a tyre with a Presta, also callled Sclaverand valve:

After unscrewing the small knurled top, give it a slight downward push to let some air escape. It will unseat the plunger. After that you can affix the chuck of your pump and the tube will fill in a breeze.

The bigger advantages of Presta are the lower weight (less imbalance in the wheel system) and the higher pressure resistance, up to 15 Bar vs 5-6 Bar for Schrader. Another advantage is that because of the screwed top they don't need a cap to prevent the ingress of dirt. The cap is required with Schrader both against leakage and dirt.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with your last paragraph. Even for bicycle purposes, Schrader valves on suspension are rated for 320psi (22bar). The non-sealing plastic cap usually found on Schrader valves both isn't sealed well enough to hold in any air and isn't strong enough anyways to do so.

Comment: Even if the limit of 5-6 bars for Schrader was true, it wouldn't be a problem in the cases enumerated by the OP (who actually said that presta are fine for road bikes). For 40mm gravel tires, the max I've seen is 4.8bars, but they are run at lower pressures anyway. 50mm+ gravel tires can have max rating lower than 4 bars, so well below 5 bars.

Comment: Schrader can be rated 8000PSI (Yes, three zeros) working pressure. While its true they typically don't put 8000psi valves in bicycle tubes, its the tire and wheel rim that limit the pressure, not the valve.

Comment: Aside, Schrader has another advantage in air shocks, where the escapement can be controlled better by knobs on the shock pump's head.

Comment: Schrader valves in airshocks play in a different league, concerning built and probably price. And @mattnz: why put something big and heavy on a roadbike if you have something light and more aerodynamic. BTW I haven't seen Schrader valves for deep section rims or suitable extensions?