# Standard or specification for diameter of valve stem holes

Tags: innertube, rims, valves

I have a rim with a Presta valve hole, but I would like to drill it out to fit a Schrader valve. Is there a specification for how large the hole should be? I want to be sure the hole isn't too big, but I also want to make sure it will fit all varieties of inner tubes I might run across in the future.

Comment: Practically speaking, schrader valves are all the same diameter. Don't take that as an endorsement of the idea of drilling out a rim, though.

Comment: Answered  here https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/schrader-tubes-in-presta-configured-rims - [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_sa-o.html) says "If you want to convert a rim drilled for Presta valves to accept Schrader valves, drill it out with a 21/64" drill bit."

Comment: Not a good idea, the rim will be weakened.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: 8mm.

The [Wikipedia page for Schrader valves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve) gives the thread size for the Schrader variant used on automobiles and bicycles.

8V1 thread: 0.305 in (7.747 mm) x 32 TPI

Be aware you need to make sure the rim has enough width to accept a larger valve hole without becoming weakened.

Comment: additionally, the enlarged hole needs to be deburred so its a smooth rolled edge, and has no way to frett through the tube's material over time.